# Building functions using WolframAlpha? Any other general examples welcome :)

Tags: functions, wolfram-alpha-queries

I want to build my own version of `SubsetQ` using `WolframAlpha` to return True or False.

```
 subsetQ[list1_, list2_] := 

 WolframAlpha[
"is list1 a subset of list2", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

How can I incorporate my arguments into the required String?

here is my failed attempt:

`"is " <> String[list1] <> "a subset of " <> String[list2]`

Note: this question is from "An Introduction to Programming *Mathematica* : P. Wellin, et al" (recommended as the first book one should work through by Shifrin's book)

Comment: Does this work `subsetQ[list1_, list2_] := 
 WolframAlpha[
  "is" <> ToString[list1] <> "a subset of" <> 
   ToString[list2], {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]`

Comment: yes it does! :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer suggested by @Hubble07 works.

```
subsetQ[list1_, list2_] := 

WolframAlpha[
"is " <> ToString[list1] <> "a subset of " <> ToString[list2],    {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

[image]